# An important information is missing from my paper under review

Tags: publications, peer-review, computer-science, errors-erratum

I have a paper under review (Second round) after a minor revision. The journal has limited page length and I contacted the editor to ask whether I can add additional pages but he said that it is only possible after acceptance. One information which I thought less important seems very crucial, where other researchers asked me about it after a presentation of my research. In addition, the lack of this information in the implementation will completely deviate the experimental results.

I am wondering how I can add it after the acceptance of the paper. Should I inform the editor for another review round?

Comment: Responding to my own question. I informed my supervisor about the situation, where his opinion is that in research is totally normal that author miss some explanation which is mainly related to the implementation part or to its importance compared to other parts in the paper. They may be wrong due to their familiarity with their work and this is the reason for the peer-review: to extract all useful information from the authors that they may miss.

Comment: He continues, since it is not a mistake and the referees did not complain about it, they may understand it and found it also abvious and does not worth to be written. Otherwise, you will find every day small technical problems in your previous papers and you will have to revise all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a crucial piece of information that alters the content (and possibly the result) of the paper, the most fair would be to contact the editor and explain the situation so that the reviewers (which seem that did not catch the missing piece) make a better and more informative decision.

The new version should be refereed. I think just adding supplementary material on an accepted (but possibly flawed or at least weaker) version is not suggested.

So: Contact the editor. S/he probably let you submit a new version which will go to the usual review channels, probably with the same reviewers. As for the page length, probably you will have to squeeze in everything, which means a lot of re-writing.